# PhantomJs with Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

I m trying to use ***phantomjs*** with ***node*** to get screen shots on a webpage.
I have almost all of it but I face issue in scrolling.
I have used ***scroll-position*** but it does not scroll correctly.

```
phantom.create()
       .then(instance => {
            return instance.createPage();
       })
       .then(page => {
            _pageInstance = page;
            return _pageInstance.open('xyz')})
.then(){ () => {

detailPage = _pageInstance.evaluate(function() {
    var pageSettings = {
        scrollToPos: [],
        elementHeight: [],
        offsetLeft: []
    };
    jQuery('li.diff-comment-activity').each(function(index, item) {
        var offsetTop = jQuery('li.diff-comment-activity .detail')[index].offsetTop;
        var elmntHeight = jQuery('li.diff-comment-activity .detail')[index].offsetHeight;
        var offsetLeft = jQuery('li.diff-comment-activity')[index].offsetLeft;
        pageSettings.scrollToPos.push(offsetTop);
        pageSettings.elementHeight.push(elmntHeight);
        pageSettings.offsetLeft.push(offsetLeft);
    });
    return pageSettings;
});
setTimeout(function() {

    console.log('Getting your screen shots...');
    detailPage.then(function(detail) {
        _details = detail;
        _pageInstance.property('viewportSize', {
            width: 1920,
            height: 1040
        });
        _details.scrollToPos.forEach(function(value, index) {
            _pageInstance.property('scrollPosition', {
                top: value
            });
            _pageInstance.property('clipRect', {
                top: 10,
                left: 300,
                width: 1400,
                height: _details.elementHeight[index]
            });
            console.log('value ' + value);
            _pageInstance.render('Image_' + index + '.jpeg', {
                format: 'jpeg',
                quality: '100'
            });
        });
    });
    console.log('Done');

}, 5000);
}
```

Here i have used ***jquery*** to get the ***offset top*** of all the elements and then used ***scrollposition*** to reach that element and then ***clip rect*** to get the screen shot.

But for few screen shots the page just scroll beyond the offset top.
*

> The intresting part is when I run the code using only phamtomJS it
>   works fine.

*
Any help ..

Comment: It seems to me that your `setTimeout` is severely misplaced. It should either include `evaluate()` or exclude the `evaluate().then()`.